# ComboBox case sensitive dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ComboBox control of DropDown type which contains items "AAA", "Aaa", "Aa+", etc.

The problem is: If I type Aaa, item "AAA" highlighted as selected, not "Aaa". I assume combobox uses FindString to find SelectedItem - so search result is equivalent to first matched item by case-insensitive string.StartsWith.

What do I need to change to override this behavior?

I need to be able to type in the ComboBox.

Is there a method in winforms I could override or some kind of property akin to WPFs [IsTextSearchCaseSensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.istextsearchcasesensitive.aspx) property from sll's answer?

Comment: Which control are you using WPF/WinForms/ASP.NET?

Comment: Stack Overflow: where good questions go to die. There mustn't have been a whitepaper or RFC for anyone to quote.

Comment: See answer on thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681886/prevent-autoselect-behavior-of-a-system-window-forms-combobox-c

Answer (score 3):

If you are using WPF, just set [IsTextSearchCaseSensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.istextsearchcasesensitive.aspx) property to true.

Comment: Unfortunately we are using windows forms, so this won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = myComboBox.Items.IndexOf("CaseSensitiveTextHere");
```