# Winforms- Stop SelectedItem being highlighted without using the style DropDownList

Tags: winforms, selecteditem, dropdown

This is about  ComboBox used in Winforms. I need to stop the selected item being heighlighted. I know I can get it done if I set the style of the combobox to ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList.
But I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to use that. Instead, at the moment what I have done is using ComboBoxStyle.DropDown.
I don't have any other option, because if I set  it to DropDown, I have to deal with some other issue in my code. It's due to something else which I cannot avoid.
Can someone suggest an alternative pls ?

Comment: Can you explain it more? What does it mean *Stop the selected item being heighlighted, like when combo box style is `DropDownList`*

Comment: When I click the mouse ( left or right ), it gets highlighted in blue colour.

Comment: Actually, mouse clicks shouldn't be allowed

Comment: And even if you could implement it, while it will act like `DropDownList` style , why do't you use that style itself?

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681886/prevent-autoselect-behavior-of-a-system-window-forms-combobox-c/25696213#25696213

Answer (score 0):

use the following  code in your form's Paint event.

```
private void myForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

or pass focus to another control in your combo box selected index changed event:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox2.Focus();
}
```

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, it didn't help.